# Nodejs rest route format conflict

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working on a Nodejs + Express project and stuck with a situation:

Here is my controller:

```
app.use('/user', router);

/* 
    GET: /user
*/
router.route('/:page?/:limit?')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        responseUtil.sendResponse(service.allRecords(req), req, res);
    });

/* 
    POST: /user
*/
router.route('/')
    .post(function(req, res) {
        responseUtil.sendResponse(service.saveRecord(req), req, res);
    });
/*
    GET: /user/1
    PUT: /user/1
    DELETE: /user/1
*/
router.route('/:id')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        responseUtil.sendResponse(service.findRecord(req), req, res);
    })
    .delete(function(req, res) {
        responseUtil.sendResponse(service.deleteRecord(req), req, res);
    })
    .put(function(req, res) {
        responseUtil.sendResponse(service.updateRecord(req), req, res);
    });
```

The problem is there is conflict in following routes:

```
/:page?/:limit?
```

and

```
/:id
```

Since, page and limit are optional, there are following possibilities:

```
/user       (all users)
/user/1     (by id)
/user/1/10  (page and limit)
/user/1     (by page)
```

How to solve this? Am I missing something in API naming convention?

Comment: I think limit and page should really be query string parameters. So you'd page like so: `/users?page=1&limit=10`. As it is you are creating unnecessary coupling. For example, as you have it now, to limit the results one always has to provide a page.

Comment: For now, I updated the route to read all users like this:

router.route('/p/:page/:limit?')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        responseUtil.sendResponse(service.allRecords(req), req, res);
    });

Answer (score 0):

You can use

- `/?user=1&page=1&limit=10` (query parameters)
- `/user/:id/page/:pageNum` (separate the url)